# Is it possible to trigger a job from Jenkins by parsing/receiving an event from Git/Gerrit Replica/Slave server?

Tags: jenkins, events, replication, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I would like to connect my Jenkins to the Git/Gerrit replica/slave server. I want my Jenkins server to start building job once a commit is merged in the replica server. It is possible with Git/Gerrit Main server, but not sure whether this can be achieved via Gerrit replica or slave server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem, I think you just need to create an additional Gerrit server at:

```
Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Add New Server
```

And point to the replica/slave server at "Hostname" and "Frontend URL" fields.